# UploadSiteHostedPictures exception error 500 when compiling: resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

Tags: c#, ebay-api

Trying to upload a picture to eBay for a product variation in an AddFixedPriceItem call.

I have copied the code into my program form here: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1093/~/.net-sample-in-c%23-for-uploadsitehostedpictures

During debugging, I double checked that the token, keys and eBay(sandbox) URL were all for the sandbox and correctly loaded into the variables. I'm not sure what else I need to do?

The code throws an exception when it hits `resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();`

> WebException: "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error"

Here is my code (without the keys):

static string UploadSiteHostedPicture(string imageUrl)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

```
    string token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserAccount.ApiToken"];
    string SandboxOrProductionURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment.ApiServerUrl"];
    string PictureURL = imageUrl;
    string DevID = "Keys were removed before posting on stackoverflow";
    string AppID = "Keys were removed before posting on stackoverflow";
    string CertID = "Keys were removed before posting on stackoverflow";
    string payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> " +
    "<UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">" +
    "<ExternalPictureURL>" + PictureURL + "</ExternalPictureURL>" +
    "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>" + token + "</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>" +
    "</UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SandboxOrProductionURL);
    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    //Add the request headers
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL", "803");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-SITEID", "0");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "UploadSiteHostedPictures");
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME", DevID);
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME", AppID);
    req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", CertID);
    //set the method to POST
    req.Method = "POST";
    //Convert the string to a byte array
    byte[] postDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);
    int len = postDataBytes.Length;
    req.ContentLength = len;
    //Post the request to eBay
    System.IO.Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, len);
    requestStream.Close();
    try
    {
        // get response and write to console
        resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse(); //THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        string output = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        resp.Close();
        XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
        xmlResponse.LoadXml(output);
        response = xmlResponse.ToString();
        //process response
        //show them how to get the full url and specify that in the AddItem request
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception caught from UploadSiteHostedPictures method:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong sandbox URL. Usually I use SOAP and I didn't realise they were different for XML calls. See here: https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/support/knowledgebase/

Also, the code above is wrong because it doesn't correctly extract the uploaded image URL from the XML response (and doesn't return it). If you want to see my noob solution for doing it then this is the code which should be inside the try block (above):

```
  try
        {
            // get response and write to console
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            string output = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            resp.Close();
            //XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
            //xmlResponse.LoadXml(output);

            string[] outputArray1 = Regex.Split(output, @"<FullURL>");
            string urlNowAtFrontOfString = outputArray1[1];
            string[] outputArray2 = Regex.Split(urlNowAtFrontOfString, @"</FullURL>");
            response = outputArray2[0];
            //process response
            //show them how to get the full url and specify that in the AddItem request
        }
```